# Java camel route never reaches otherwise statement

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am creating a service that transfers a file to a new location based on the file name. Problem is that the second otherwise statement is never reached even if the first when is false (file name doesn't start with "START"). Also, the from uri has delete=true option, maybe that influences something. Result is that file is just deleted.

```java
        <route id="outgoing" errorHandlerRef="outgoingDeadLetterErrorHandler">
            <from uri="OutgoingSource"/>

            <choice>
                <when>
                    <simple>${file:name} starts with 'START'</simple>

                    <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>
                    <choice>
                        <when>
                            <xpath>/File/Header/@x = 'X'</xpath>
                            <to ref="OutgoingErrorDestination"/>
                        </when>
                        <when>
                            <xpath>/Header/@y = 'Y'</xpath>
                            <to ref="OutgoingDestination"/>
                        </when>
                        <otherwise>
                            <to ref="OutgoingErrorDestination"/>
                        </otherwise>
                    </choice>
                </when>
                <otherwise>
                    <to ref="OutgoingErrorDestination"/>
                </otherwise>
            </choice>
        </route>
```

Comment: How do you know the exchange is not delivered to the endpoint `OutgoingErrorDestination`? Did you try adding a `log` to see if anything is delivered here? Camel `File2` component with `delete=true` will delete source file after consumption.

Comment: yes, I had logging added, and it never reached it.

Answer (score 0):

file:name is relative to the starting directory (i.e. file:name = test\hello.txt)

If you want to test only the filename you should use file:onlyname.noext

```
<simple>${file:onlyname.noext} starts with 'START'</simple>
```